# Datatables Individual Column Search incompatible with scroll

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

I am using [Datatables](https://www.datatables.net/) to display more than a thousand table rows. I use the [individual column search](https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html) to search specific columns. I initialize the table with:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        "scrollX": true,
        "scrollY": "400px",
        "paging": false
    });
```

However, when I search a column the second left column is overflown with the first (fixed) one. (Please see the picture below.)

[image: the company field is partly behind the username]

I suspect this is because the reassigning of width of the columns after each search: the first column used to contain longer usernames as well, but after the search, it has a smaller width.

I tried setting a right margin to the first column, but it did not help.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Please find a jsfiddle demostrating the issue [here](http://jsfiddle.net/syg47mtp/1/). You should search career for "J".

Comment: do you have any code or jsfiddle that you can include in the question.

Comment: I added a link to a fiddle, thank you for the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been known to datatables support for some time. (see [thread](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/issues/553)) The issue has already been fixed with [this changeset](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/commit/17130d2fd54aac95bd39c88d830d71a73ad06487), and is said to be due to:

> When scrolling is enabled and column visiblity is toggled a Javascript
>   error would occur due to **the column width calculation method cloning
>   the wrong header element.**

Datatables' [latest nightly release](http://datatables.net/download/index) already has this fixed, however the fix is two lines, which can be easily added to the current version, as well.

Note, that this issue has affected ColVis, Individual Column Search and Fixed Columns as well.

Answer (score 0):

Datatables recalculates the column width after the Ajax rendering so I think that's a normal behavior, but for your case , you could prevent the overflown by eliminating

```
new $.fn.dataTable.FixedColumns( table );
```